# how to add stylesheet in drupal site?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am new to Drupal.

I am in need to add an external stylesheet to an existing site. I see drupal_add_css() to be used to add stylesheet.

I tried to add this function my template.php, but it is not making any change.
Neither it is adding stylsheet nor throwing any error in console.

This is what I did

```
function drupal_add_css()
{
$path = '/css/new_style.css';
$type = 'module'; 
$media = 'all'; 
$preprocess = TRUE;
}
```

I have added the above snippet in my theme's template.php

How do I add the new_style.css to an existing array of stylesheet.- **$Style**

The existing theme name is 9ways

Plus this stylesheet should be the first css to be included.

The drupal version being used is **v6.0**

Comment: [Did you try and google?](https://www.drupal.org/node/171209)

Comment: yes, I didm but its not rendering

Comment: @Epodax can you please suggest some answer?

Comment: I did, I posted a link, apart from that then no, I don't use drupal.

Comment: links, checked by me 1)http://themery.com/dgd7/advanced-theming/css/add-remove-replace 2)https://www.drupal.org/node/82758

Comment: @Epodax where you have posted the link

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to override [`drupal_add_css()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7.x) you want to use it.

In your template.php you need to define the hook you want to use to add your CSS file.  If you want a page-specific CSS file you can define a [`hook_preprocess_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6.x) and use `drupal_add_css()` in that hook:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
   ...check for page you want to add css for...
   drupal_add_css( drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/css/pagestyles.css', 'theme');
}
```

That said if you want a css file as part of your theme on all your pages you don't want to add it using `drupal_add_css()`, you should use the .info file and include the file there:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
```

*Take Note: Drupal 6 is no longer officially supported by the community. While there are some places that are offering long term support for Drupal 6, you should plan to move to Drupal 7 or 8 soon.*

Comment: developer prior to me.. has named the theme as 9ways, as the function name should start with the theme name, it doesn't allow, how to overcome this

Comment: You can create a subtheme based on the poorly named theme, a custom module that does the same thing, or fix (rename) the main theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can try module css injector 
https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector

With this module you can inject css style, you must reference the id or class